# Modifying a C string: access violation

Tags: c++, c, string

> **Possible Duplicates:**
>   [Why does simple C code receive segmentation fault?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/164194/why-does-simple-c-code-receive-segmentation-fault)
>   [Modifying C string constants?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/480555/modifying-c-string-constants)

Why does this code generate an access violation?

```
int main()
{
    char* myString = "5";
    *myString = 'e'; // Crash
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Before answering that question, let me ask you one: why did you choose to enclose the '5' in double-quotes and the 'e' in single-quotes?

Comment: This question gets asked about once a week on SO :), give me a minute to find the original and I'll link you to it.

Comment: C or C++? Knowing which language you are coding in would be useful.

Comment: @Sev: Because one is a string and the other is a character.

Comment: @ Sev: Let me answer that: Because myString is a char *array* (i.e., C-style string), and *myString is the first character in the array. "5" is actually { '5', '\0' }.

Comment: @sth: '5' and 'e' both cannot be considered characters?

Comment: Duplicae of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/164194/why-does-simple-c-code-receive-segmentation-fault

Comment: "X" is a string ( 'X' + '\0' ) 'X' is just a character

Comment: @ Daniel Daranas: Does it really make a difference? If you can't tell from the source, usually not.

Comment: Here's one thread:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1011455/is-it-possible-to-modify-a-string-of-char-in-c/1011481

Comment: My point was that if the OP initialized it to "e" it would result in the same problem, no?

Comment: @DevSolar: It does make a difference. In one case I can recommend the user to use std::string, in the other, I can recommend an album by The Cure :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

*mystring is apparently pointing at read-only static memory. C compilers may allocate string literals in read-only storage, which may not be written to at run time.

Answer (score 2):

String literals are considered constant.

Answer (score 0):

The correct way of writing your code is:

```
const char* myString = "5";
*myString = 'e'; // Crash
return 0;
```

You should always consider adding 'const' in such cases, so it's clear that changing this string may cause unspecified behavior.