# error by creating process

Tags: c++, windows

hello i want to get startet with programming with WIN32, therefore i wrote a programm that creates a process but in the line of code where i create the process the programm gets an error an dosn't work (abend). i don't know if the code in programm 1 is wrong or the code in the second programm that should be created by the first. ( I don't know if the code in the first programm after "createprocess" is right because i didn't get further with debugging, because in this line i get the error.(i tested it without the cout,waitforobject and close handle but i didn't work either )).

First Programm:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <windows.h>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

void main()
{

bool ret;
bool retwait;

STARTUPINFO startupinfo;
GetStartupInfo (&startupinfo);

PROCESS_INFORMATION pro2info;

    ret = CreateProcess(NULL, L"D:\\betriebssystemePRA1PRO2.exe", NULL, NULL, false, CREATE_NEW_CONSOLE, NULL,
        NULL, &startupinfo, &pro2info);


    cout<<"hProcess: "<<pro2info.hProcess<<endl;
    cout<<"dwProcessId: "<<pro2info.dwProcessId <<endl;

    retwait= WaitForSingleObject (pro2info.hProcess, 100);
    retwait= WaitForSingleObject (pro2info.hProcess, 100);

    CloseHandle (pro2info.hProcess);//prozesshandle schließen 

    retwait= WaitForSingleObject (pro2info.hProcess, 100);



ExitProcess(0);


}
```

Seconde Programm:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <windows.h>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

void main()
{


    int b;

    b=GetCurrentProcessId();

    cout<<b<<endl;
    cout<<"Druecken Sie Enter zum Beenden"<<endl;
    cin.get();
        //warten bis Benutzer bestätigt

    Sleep (700);
    ExitProcess(0);

    cout<<"test";
}
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: What error is CreateProcess() returning?  If it is returning 0, what is does GetLastError() give you?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Notice the type of the `lpCommandLine` parameter to `CreateProcess` -- it is `LPTSTR`, not `LPCTSTR`, i.e. it is *not* `const`.

This means that **`CreateProcess` reserves the right to actually modify** the contents of `lpCommandLine`.  However, you have provided a pointer to a string literal as parameter, and string literals are immutable (they come from your program's read-only data segment and attempts to alter them will typically result in an access violation error.)

To fix this, simply **change your code [not to use an immutable string literal](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/480555#480705)**:

```
wchar_t wcsCommandLine[] = L"D:\\betriebssystemePRA1PRO2.exe";
ret = CreateProcess(NULL, wcsCommandLine, NULL, NULL, ...
```

Interestingly enough, `CreateProcessW` (UNICODE) attempts to write to `lpCommandLine` whereas `CreateProcessA` (ANSI) does not, and surprise -- your first program is built as UNICODE (were you to build it as ANSI it would work out of the box, at least on Windows XP.)

I can confirm that, with the above modification, your code works.

Also note that:

- unless you need to specify `D:\\betriebssystemePRA1PRO2.exe`'s window title, position etc. you **do not need to supply a `STARTUPINFO` structure at all**, you can simply pass `lpStartupInfo` as `NULL` and a default will be used
- you should not be calling `WaitForSingleObject` on a closed handle

Answer (score 3):

You must set the size of the `startupinfo` struct:

```
startupinfo.cb = sizeof(startupinfo);
```

Maybe this is why `CreateProcess` is failing.

And by the way - why are you calling `GetStartupInfo`? You should just zero out the memory of `startupinfo` (besides setting the size as mentioned above).

See an example [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms682512(VS.85).aspx).

Comment: `GetStartupInfo` sets up `cb` (as well as window title, position etc.)  Granted, he did not have to call `GetStartupInfo` -- he does not even have to create and initialize `STARTUPINFO` struct as he can simply pass `NULL` and have `CreateProcess` use defaults.

Comment: Forgetting to specify the size is such a common error I thought this might be the cause. But if GetStartupInfo already fills it, then you are right. Maybe in my mind I already removed the GetStartupInfo-call. +1 for your answer.