# constness in c strings

Tags: c++, string

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Modifying C string constants?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/480555/modifying-c-string-constants)

As far as I understand if you want to make a c string constant you should give a declaration like :

```
const char* str = "hello";
```

or

```
char* const str = "hello";
```

But a simple declaration like:

```
char* str = "hello"
```

If I try to modify the string by any means - like

```
str[2] = 'f';
```

or

```
*(str+2) = 'f';
```

I always get a segmentation fault, why is that ?

Also if I do a declaration like

```
const char* const str = "hello";
str = "bye";
```

as per scott meyers I am trying to modify a const pointer and should get warning, error or segfault, but I get nothing and code compiles and executes perfectly. I am puzzled, I am using g++ on ubuntu 11.10.

Comment: Yes, I'm puzzled, too. Any conforming compiler should reject the last snippet of code shown. If yours doesn't, it contains a bug. Before blaming the compiler, ensure that you're not ignoring any warnings.

Comment: *The code compiles and executes properly* because modifying a string literal results in an **Undefined Behavior** which means all safe bets are off,your program might work or might crash or show any weird behavior.An Undefined Behavior implies that the program is ill-formed and can show a behavior which may or may not be explained.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
char* str = "hello";
```

String literal `hello` resides in read only location and cannot be modified. Compiler should emit a warning regarding the initialization of identifier `str`.

To actually modify the string, you need to do -

```
char str[] = "hello"; // Copying the string literal hello to the array str

str[2] = 'f';  // Now these are valid.
str[2] = 'f';
```

Answer (score 4):

> ```
> char* str = "hello"
> ```

This makes use of a deprecated conversion that allows a string literal to be implicitly converted to a `char*`.  Do not make use of this conversion.

The characters in the string literal are still const, despite the fact that you are making `str` point to the string literal.

> ```
> const char* const str = "hello";
> str = "bye";
> ```

This code is ill-formed.  Your compiler should reject it.

If your compiler does not reject this code or does not at least issue a diagnostic message (warning), it is either a bug in the compiler or a "language extension."