# Change string literal in C through pointer?

Tags: c, string

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Why do I get a segmentation fault when writing to a string?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/164194/why-do-i-get-a-segmentation-fault-when-writing-to-a-string)

I have the following program:

```
char *s     = "abcdf";
char s1[50] = "abcdf";

s1[0] = 'Q';   // Line 1
s[0] = 'P';    // Line 2
```

Why `Line 1` worked correctly and `Line 2` caused the program to crash?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why do I get a segmentation fault when writing to a string?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/164194/why-do-i-get-a-segmentation-fault-when-writing-to-a-string), [Is it possible to modify a string of char in C?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1011455/is-it-possible-to-modify-a-string-of-char-in-c/1011481), and [Modifying C string constants?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/480555/modifying-c-string-constants).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Line 2 points to the data section of your executable which is read-only, whereas in line 1, the program initializes `s1` array with the given string. This is stored in stack, which you can modify.

Answer (score 3):

```
char *s = "abcdf";
char s1[50] = "abcdf";
s1[0] = 'Q'; // Line 1
s[0] = 'P'; // Line 2
```

Here, `s` is a guaranteed modifiable pointer that may be a global variable or local stack variable depending on whether you put that definition at program scope or inside a function.  Sometime before you start using it, the compiler's required to arrange for the the *address* of the text "abcdf" to be loaded into `s`.  Typically in modern Operating Systems, "abcdf" itself will be in an area of read-only memory, where the "loader" that reads the program file into memory in preparation for execution tells the CPU itself to allow read but not write operations.  So `s` - which is modifiable - points to "abcdf" which is not.

`s1` is a guaranteed modifiable array of 50 characters.  Sometime before you start using it, the compiler's required to arrange for the text "abcdf" to be *copied* into that modifiable buffer.  You can then modify that buffer safely as you do with `s1[0] = 'Q'`.

`s[0] = 'P'` uses the pointer `s` to find the original non-modifiable / constant text "abcdf" in read-only memory, then tries to change it.  As mentioned above, the CPU will typically have been configured to react by generating a CPU exception/trap/signal/interrupt (terminology differs with manufacturer).  Your program will fail.