# C, assign a pointed value to a pointed value, like *a=*b;

Tags: c, pointers, variable-assignment

If I want to change the pointed value without changing the pointer's address, what should I do?

In 3, `*d=*b` will return segmentation fault in running time. I think it is because the `*d` is not pointed to any memory space. This also explains why 2, works. However, for 1, `*a` and `*b` pointed to memory with same size, why it will return segmentation fault here?

```
void main(void){
    char *a="abcd";
    char *b="1234";
    char *c=(char *)malloc(sizeof(char));
    char *d;
    *a=*b; //1.segmentation fault
    *c=*b; //2.ok
    *d=*b; //3.segmentation fault
}
```

Comment: You cannot change string literals. Any attempt at modifying them gives undefined behavior. This code cannot work.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why do I get a segmentation fault when writing to a string initialized with "char \*s" but not "char s\[\]"?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/164194/why-do-i-get-a-segmentation-fault-when-writing-to-a-string-initialized-with-cha), http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10202013/change-string-literal-in-c-through-pointer, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1011455/is-it-possible-to-modify-a-string-of-char-in-c/1011481, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/480555/modifying-c-string-constants

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because strings, such as `"abcd"` are constant in C. It is undefined behaviour to try to modify one.

If you want the string to be modifiable, you have to declare it like this:

```
char a[] = "abcd";
```

This will declare a local array and initialise it with the content of the string (which is different from declaring a pointer which points to the string)

Comment: so what if I want to copy and create a new string and make `a` point to it?

Comment: Then the array approach (above) is not the one you should choose.

Answer (score 2):

Constant strings are usually stored in read only memory and you can't modify them.

To make them writable create a copy first:

```
char *a = strdup("abcd");
```