# accessing violation writing location

Tags: c, string, exception

I've written a code to remove special chars from string. But, getting the exception as written in the heading. Using VS2012.. Any solutions?

```
void remover(char *input)
{
int j = 0;
char *temp = (char *) malloc(sizeof(char)*strlen(input));
for(int i = 0 ; input[i] != '\0' ; i++)
{
    if(isalpha(input[i]) || isdigit(input[i]))
    {
        *temp[j] = *input[i];
        j++;
    }
}

*temp[j] = '\0';
for(j = 0 ; temp[j] != '\0' ; j++)
    *input[j] = *temp[j];   // exception here

*input[j] = '\0';
//free(temp);
}
```

Comment: I suspectn "input" might be a string literal.  String literals are stored in read-only memory - you cannot modify them.  Look here for more details: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/480555/modifying-c-string-constants

Comment: solutions for that? 
even string copy wont work?

Comment: Show the code that calls `remover`.

Comment: The "solution" is to copy into read-write memory, like you're doing with "temp".  You just can't write from "temp" back into "input", if "input" happens to be a string constant!  You *can* copy input into another variable (e.g. with strcpy), and pass that other variable input "remover()".

Comment: okay got it!! 
i have atruct with *input and *output variable.. changed it to input[50] and output[50] it works now

Comment: What possessed you to write `*(input+j)` instead of `input[j]`?

Answer (score 1):

First, you need to add 1 in your malloc for the final '\0', but this is not your problem.

How are you testing it? You can't modify strings literals so `remover("Test")` will not be allowed and you should instead return the new string (temp) and have you caller decide when to free it or if it wants to free the original.

Comment: The "can't modify constant strings" is undoubtedly the problem.

Comment: but according to the question, the original string is to be modified :/ any solution?

Comment: @VishalSharma How can you modify that which is unmodifiable? Stop passing unmodifiable strings?