# Confusion between char* and char[] in qsort()

Tags: c++, qsort

In the standard `qsort()` function declared in `<stdlib.h>`, it crashes when I do the following:

```
char *arr[]={"abc","def"};
qsort((void*)arr[i],strlen(arr[i]),sizeof(char),compare);
```

For it to work, I have to use it like this:

```
int len=strlen(arr[i]);
char *buffer=new char[len+1];
strcpy(buffer, arr[i]);        
qsort((void*)buffer,strlen(arr[i]),sizeof(char),compare);
```

Why is the first method not working when the declaration of `qsort()` also specifies `void*` as its first argument?

I know that in the first method, what I am passing is not an array, but isn't `char*` always treated as an array?

If not, then what are the cases when it's not treated as an array?

Comment: char* is always treated as char*, its just that there is no real support for strings in C, so they settled on char* representing string. Also, your question is marked as C++, so please consider using std::string and std::sort instead

Comment: You don't need to cast *to* `void *` and second parameter is *quantity to sort* (so should be 2 and not 3).

Comment: @Creris: That's not quite true. C does support strings; there's just no data type called `string`. A string is by definition "a contiguous sequence of characters terminated by and including the first null character". A `char*` is not a string, though it may point to a string.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The elements of the array `arr` are non-const pointers to string constants. Trying to modify what they point to (i.e. the string constant) via `qsort()` yields undefined behaviour. This is different from the scenario `char p[] = "some string";`, in which case you initialize the array `p` with the content of the string literal, then you can modify `p` with no problems. 
The correct definition of `char* arr[]` should be `const char* arr[]`, precisely to prevent these kind of issues.

If you compile with all warnings on and with a C++ compiler you should get an warning similar to

> > warning: ISO C++ forbids converting a string constant to 'char*' [-Wpedantic]

A plain C compiler seem to emit no warnings, but it is still undefined behaviour.

Closely related: [Why do I get a segmentation fault when writing to a string initialized with "char *s" but not "char s[]"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/164194/why-do-i-get-a-segmentation-fault-when-writing-to-a-string) and [Modifying C string constants?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/480555/modifying-c-string-constants)