# C is ignoring byte assignment?

Tags: c, arm, embedded, keil

Im doing something wrong.

This is the piece of code from ARM code (Keil5 IDE):

```
uint8_t * at_ss_data = (uint8_t *)("\n\rAT$SS=AA AA\n\r");
at_ss_data[12] = 0;
```

but the 12th index (the last `A`) does not change in the variable when the code is pushed to the ARM embedded board.

My goal is to change the `AA AA` substring in the `at_ss_data` array to `00 00`

Comment: Modifying a string literal is undefined behavior.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1704407/what-is-the-difference-between-char-s-and-char-s-in-c

Comment: @Notlikethat: In C, string literals are **not** of type `char const *`. You're thinking of c++.

Comment: Or another one : [Modifying C string constants?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/480555/modifying-c-string-constants) (it's last, I stop to search other same question)

Comment: @Garf365: One unfortunate problem with those Q&A's is that the answers focus on the observed behavior, rather than clarifying that the behavior is *undefined*. In particular, in this case there is no segfault.

Comment: @EOF it's on embedded device, string is certainly stored in flash, so read-only

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/118427/discussion-between-eof-and-garf365).

Comment: @EOF: Formally correct. But they are nevertheless immutable and in typical implementations technically identical with `const char []`. They are never `const char * ` nor `char *` which are pointers. Neither in C nor C++.

Comment: @Olaf If they *were* of type (or "technically identical to", whatever that would mean to you) `char const []`, you could not convert them to `char *` by assignment.

Comment: @EOF: That's why I wrote "technically". gcc e.g. puts them into `.rodata` section - the same it puts `const char []` into. The assignment to a `char *` is some legacy not to break "problematic" code. That this works with a pointer is the standard automatic conversion of an array to a "pointer to the first element".

Comment: @Olaf: Nothing "technically" about it. String literals *do not have* type `char const[]`. If they *did*, the compiler could catch this kind of problem, *but they do not*. This is important. Teach people to understand C's type system, or they'll be perpetually confused.

Comment: @EOF: Types are semantical, not technical. Where exactly did I write a string literal has `const char []`? They are not `const char *` nor `char *` either, but `char []` in C and `const char []` in C++! Anyway, either I cannot make clear what I mean or you don't want to understand. Either way, this is useless.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You must not modify a string literal (which is [undefined behavior](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior)). You should use an array initialized with a string literal.

This way, your code should be:

```
uint8_t at_ss_data[] = "\n\rAT$SS=AA AA\n\r";
at_ss_data[12] = 0;
```

Answer (score 2):

at_ss_data is pointing to read-only memory, you can't change string literal like this. This behavior is undefined.
instead you may try something like this:

```
uint8_t at_ss_data[] = "\n\rAT$SS=AA AA\n\r";
```

This array is now writable.

Comment: _you are allocating memory on the stack_.... It depends on the scope of the array.

Comment: FWIW, it is undefined behaviour, probably made so because string literals *often* reside in read-only memory, so you should treat them as such. But they do not always reside in read-only memory.