# C - string concatenation with pointers

Tags: c, pointers, c-strings, string-literals, strcat

why does the following string concatenation does not work?

```
main()
{
char *str1 = "United";
char *str2= "Front";
char *str3;
str3 = strcat(str1, str2 ) ;
printf("\n%s",str3 );

}
```

I got this problem in exercise questions in one of a book on pointers. The question mentions

> [Q] Is the code correct if not why and also correct the code.

Comment: _...does not work..._ What does that mean? Why should it work and what should it do? What errors/issues are you facing?

Comment: 1) because the concatenation target `str1` does not have enough memory for the concatenation, and 2) because string literals such as `str1` should be treated as read-only. It would work with `char str1[12] = "United";`

Comment: That very same book should tell you some details about string literals, pointers and how those string functions work. Did you try to combine these pieces of information?

Comment: @B001ᛦ the main problem could be that he might not even face any error on some systems. Still the code is crap.

Comment: Before you post, please consider searching the web for information.

Comment: @B001ᛦ it's a question in a book, not a coding problem encountered by the OP.

Answer (score 1):

See my answer to the question [concatenation of character arrays in c](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56643131/concatenation-of-character-arrays-in-c/56643312#56643312)

You may not change string literals.

This statement

```
str3 = strcat(str1, str2 ) ;
```

tries to change the string literal `str1` and moreover tries to write beyond the string literal.

To make a concatenated string you have to allocate a memory large enough to contain the both strings.

What you need is the following

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(void) 
{
    const char *str1 = "United";
    const char *str2 = "Front";

    char *str3 = malloc( strlen( str1 ) + strlen( str2 ) + 1 );

    strcpy( str3, str1 );
    puts( strcat( str3, str2 ) );

    free( str3 );

    return 0;
}
```

The program output is

```
UnitedFront
```

Answer (score 0):

When you write `char* s = "something"` a piece of read-only memory is allocated. More on this [here](https://cs50.stackexchange.com/a/9281/22780).

The declaration of `strcat` looks like this:

```
char *strcat( char *dest, const char *src );
```

Basically what it will do is append `src` to `dest`, but since your destination, `str1` does not have enough memory to hold both strings.

So what I would do is, either use `snprintf` with a pre-allocated buffer or:

```
char *str1 = "United";
char *str2 = "Front";

char *buf = calloc(strlen(str1) + strlen(str2) + 1, sizeof(char));

strncpy(buf, str1, strlen(str1));
strncat(buf, str2, strlen(str2));

printf("%s", buf);
```

Or with `snprintf`:

```
char *str1 = "United";
char *str2 = "Front";

int buf_len = strlen(str1) + strlen(str2) + 1;
char *buf = calloc(buf_len, sizeof(char));

snprintf(buf, buf_len, "%s%s", str1, str2);
```

Comment: `strncpy(dest, src, strlen(src));` is exactly equivalent to plain `strcpy(dest, src);`.  There's really no point using `strncpy()` there.  Oh, and `sizeof (char)` can only be 1, since it measures size in units of `char`.

Answer (score -1):

The first parameter of `strcat` (`str1` in your case) needs to have enough allocated memory to hold the concatenated string.
You can either create it with `malloc` or declare it as an array with a big enough size.

Comment: since *str1 is a char pointer and now it holds the starting address of the string "united " why can't we add " front" next to its memory ?                                       i

Comment: @bigbrother because you don't own any memory at this location to store the extra `char`s.